# Trying to convert XML to JSON for JsTree (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm trying to create some local app. I used to learn how to dev, but havent practiced at all for 7 years. And i'm pretty rusty.

I have an HTML page with an input. This input should be a XML file.
The aim is to build a tree of that file using JsTree, and when i click on one of the "leaf", showing the description in another div.

Well, i handled the "div" part. But i have some troubles with file reading.

This is what my XML file looks like (just a sample) :

```
<offres>
    <formation>
        <domaine-formation>
            <groupName>domaine-formation</groupName>
            <groupDesc>Cet élément contient des listes de codes décrivant le dormaine de la formation, en utilisant les nomenclatures NSF (Nomenclatures des Spécialités de Formation), ROME (Répertoire Opérationnel des Métiers et des Emplois) et/ou le FORMACODE (thésaurus de l'offre de formation du Centre Inffo). Règle de gestion : le premier code FORMACODE doit être considéré comme le FORMACODE principal.</groupDesc>
            <occMin>1</occMin>
            <occMax>1</occMax>
            <code-FORMACODE>
                <dataName>code-FORMACODE</dataName>
                <dataType>Alphanumérique</dataType>
                <dataPresence>Conditionnel</dataPresence>
                <minLength>5</minLength>
                <maxLength>5</maxLength>
                <dataDesc2>Cet élément contient un code du FORMACODE. Il est obligatoire de préciser grâce à l'attribut 'ref' la version du FORMACODE utilisée (par exemple 'V10' pour la version 10 du FORMACODE).</dataDesc2>
                <txcompOI>99.7</txcompOI>
            </code-FORMACODE>
            <code-NSF>
                <dataName>code-NSF</dataName>
                <dataType>Alphanumérique</dataType>
                <dataPresence>Facultatif</dataPresence>
                <minLength>3</minLength>
                <maxLength>3</maxLength>
                <dataDesc2>Cet élément contient un code de la NSF (3 postes).</dataDesc2>
                <txcompOI>75.4</txcompOI>
            </code-NSF>
            <code-RNCP>
                <dataName>code-RNCP</dataName>
                <dataType>Alphanumérique</dataType>
                <dataPresence>Facultatif</dataPresence>
                <minLength>1</minLength>
                <maxLength>6</maxLength>
                <dataDesc2>Cet élément contient un code d'une certification dans le Répertoire National des Certifications Professionnelles.</dataDesc2>
                <txcompOI>34.6</txcompOI>
            </code-RNCP>
            <extras></extras> 
        </domaine-formation>
        <intitule-formation>
            <dataName>intitule-formation</dataName>
            <dataType>Alphanumérique</dataType>
            <dataPresence>Obligatoire</dataPresence>
            <minLength>1</minLength>
            <maxLength>255</maxLength>
            <dataDesc1>Intitulé qui sert à caractériser et singulariser une action de formation. Il en indique le titre.</dataDesc1>
            <dataDesc2>Cet élément décrit l'intitulé de la formation. Si la formation a comme résultat l'obtention d'un diplôme, le contenu de cet élément devrait utiliser une dénomination conforme aux tables de l'Éducation Nationale. Si la formation a comme résultat un titre ou une certification, le contenu devrait utiliser une dénomination conforme au contenu du Répertoire National des Certifications Professionnelles (RNCP).</dataDesc2>
            <txcompOI>100</txcompOI>
        </intitule-formation>
        <objectif-formation>
            <dataName>objectif-formation</dataName>
            <dataType>Alphanumérique</dataType>
            <dataPresence>Obligatoire</dataPresence>
            <minLength>1</minLength>
            <maxLength>3000</maxLength>
            <dataDesc1>Il peut s'agir d'une session de certification, de professionnalisation, de préparation à la qualification, de remise à niveau, de (re)mobilisation, de perfectionnement ou de création d'entreprise. Ces catégories sont de type administratif et sont décrites ci-dessous.</dataDesc1>
            <dataDesc2>Cet élément décrit l'objectif de la formation. Il décrit la ou les compétences à acquérir, à améliorer ou à entretenir.</dataDesc2>
            <txcompOI>89.9</txcompOI>
        </objectif-formation>
    </formation>
</offres>
```

And this is the JsTree i wanna have :

```
offres
 -- formation
 -- -- domaine-formation
 -- -- -- code-FORMACODE
 -- -- -- code-NSF
 -- -- -- code-RNCP
 -- -- intitule-formation
 -- -- objectif-formation
```

If you have any idea on how to do it, would be nice.
I'm struggling. If i should rework the XML file, just say it too :)

Edit : [This is actually what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtXLA.png)

Edit : If that can help, here is my code to get the image in the link right above.

```
var loadXmlButton = document.getElementById('loadXmlButton');
loadXmlButton.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelection, false);

function handleFileSelection() {
    var file = loadXmlButton.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();

    waitForTextReadComplete(reader);
    reader.readAsText(file);

    fileName = file.name;
    fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    // On remplace le champs de sélection du fichier par le nom du fichier chargé
    $("#dataFileName").text('Norme '+ fileName.toUpperCase());
}

function waitForTextReadComplete(reader) {
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
        var text = event.target.result;

        parseTextAsXml(text);
    }
}

function parseTextAsXml(text) {
    var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(text, 'text/xml')

    var parser = new DOMParser(),
        xmlDom = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

        $(function () {
            // var sHTML = drawTreeFromXml(xmlDom);
            var sHTML = xmlToJson(xml.documentElement)

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#tree-container').jstree({
                    'core' : {
                        'data' : sHTML,
                        'themes' : {
                            'responsive' : true
                        }
                    },
                    "search": {
                        "case_insensitive": true,
                        "show_only_matches" : true
                    },
                    plugins: ["search"]
                }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                    var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
                    var parentId = data.node.a_attr.parent_id;
                    if(href == '#')
                    return '';

                    //window.open(href);
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(href).offset().top-65)},'slow');

                });

                $('#tree-container').slimScroll({
                    height: '480px',
                    start: 'top'
                });

            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                $('#tree-container').jstree('search', $(this).val());
            });            
        });
    });
}

function xmlToJson(xmlNode) {
    return {
        text: xmlNode.firstChild && xmlNode.firstChild.nodeType === 3 ? 
                  xmlNode.firstChild.textContent : '',
        children: [...xmlNode.children].map(childNode => xmlToJson(childNode))
    };
}
```

loadXmlButton is my input.
tree-container is the div where the tree is supposed to load.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function to convert XML to JSON

```
// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {
    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
    // do attributes
    if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
            var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
            obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        }
    }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

And then, you can use it with JSTree:

```
var xml = `<offres>
    <formation>
        <domaine-formation>
            <groupName>domaine-formation</groupName>
            <groupDesc>Cet élément contient des listes de codes décrivant le dormaine de la formation, en utilisant les nomenclatures NSF (Nomenclatures des Spécialités de Formation), ROME (Répertoire Opérationnel des Métiers et des Emplois) et/ou le FORMACODE (thésaurus de l'offre de formation du Centre Inffo). Règle de gestion : le premier code FORMACODE doit être considéré comme le FORMACODE principal.</groupDesc>
            <occMin>1</occMin>
            <occMax>1</occMax>
            <code-FORMACODE>
                <dataName>code-FORMACODE</dataName>
                <dataType>Alphanumérique</dataType>
                <dataPresence>Conditionnel</dataPresence>
                <minLength>5</minLength>
                <maxLength>5</maxLength>
                <dataDesc2>Cet élément contient un code du FORMACODE. Il est obligatoire de préciser grâce à l'attribut 'ref' la version du FORMACODE utilisée (par exemple 'V10' pour la version 10 du FORMACODE).</dataDesc2>
                <txcompOI>99.7</txcompOI>
            </code-FORMACODE>
        </domaine-formation>
    </formation>
</offres>`,
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );

$('#using_json').jstree({ 'core' : xmlToJson(xmlDoc) });
```

Comment: I've tried your code and i pretty get nothing at all.
Even while using it alone. 
I tried to change 'core' : xmlToJson(xmlDoc) }) with 'core' : { 'data' : xmlToJson(xmlDoc) } }). And i get a single folder with no name (and no child) in the jstree.