# How can I convert this ternary syntax to an if/else statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, ternary-operator

I'm trying to convert `XML` to `JSON` and came across the following function. But I need to modify some things on the fly. So I want to convert this function to an if/else statement or a loop.

Could you help me ?

```
function xmlToJson(xmlNode) {
    return {
        text: xmlNode.firstChild && xmlNode.firstChild.nodeType === 3 ? 
              xmlNode.firstChild.textContent : '',
        children: [...xmlNode.children].map(childNode => xmlToJson(childNode))
    };
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: whats your xml and what you are trying to achieve like the expected output (JSON)

Comment: This seems off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I've asked in another topic, giving all infos i had. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605008/trying-to-convert-xml-to-json-for-jstree-javascript-jquery
Since i had no answer working (i'm not blaming anyone :D), i've been trying different scripts, including this one, but i couldnt understand how it worked.

Comment: I wonder where that function came from

Comment: From this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535253/populating-jstree-from-xml-string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `xmlNode.children` is an array, you could do something like this:

```
function xmlToJson(xmlNode)
{
    let obj = {};
    if (xmlNode.firstChild && xmlNode.firstChild.nodeType === 3)
    {
        obj.text = xmlNode.firstChild.textContent;
    }
    else
    {
        obj.children = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < xmlNode.children.length; ++i)
        {
           obj.children.push(xmlToJson(xmlNode.children[i]));
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```